# Tkinter TopLevel not showing when it's supposed to

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a very simple python code: a tkitner button that process some images in the background. I wanted to open a tkinter toplevel to show the user that it was doing something, but for my surprise is not working as I thought it would. The command on the `tk.Button` is the next method:

```
def processing(self):
        """Starts the images processing"""
        # Open a Tk.Toplevel
        aux_topLevel = Splash(self.window) # a simple Tk.Toplevel class, that works perfectly
        self._process_images() # starts processing the images
        # I wanted to kill here the topLevel created before
        aux_topLevel.destroy()
```

My surprise: the window is displayed once the processing images is done (tried it out adding prints and time.sleep), however, i couldn't display the TopLevel when I wanted to.

Is there anything am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can't tell given how little code you have shared but my guess would be that `_process_images()` is a method that takes quite a while to execute and takes up all the CPU time and the GUI is prevented from being updated. If you share more of your code, methods to fix this could be suggested.

Comment: Solutions might include: using the tk `update` method or using threading to split the image processing in to a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example and try to run it.

What you'd think should happen is that the new Toplevel window should open, some event happens for a period of time and then the window is destroyed.

What actually happens is the window is opened, but never displayed, the task occurs and then the window is destroyed.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def processing():
    new = Toplevel(root)
    new.geometry("200x150")
    lbl = Label(new,text="--")
    lbl.grid()
    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #Un-comment the line below to fix
        #root.update()
        print(i)
        lbl['text'] = "{}".format(i)
    new.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
btnGo = Button(root,text="Go",command=processing)
btnGo.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

If you un-comment out the `root.update()` line and re-run the code, the window will be displayed.

There are better ways to deal with tasks that takes a while to process, such as threading.